# Not able to install Oracle developer suite 10g on window 7

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am try to install oracle developer suite 10g (32bit) on window 7.

Actually I want to install oracle form which is in complete option of Installation window. 
I have already solved swap memory issue and compatibility issues.
oracle developer suite 10g Installer met all Requirement.

I have passed all requirement with is follow snap-shot:

[image]

After I got Installation window, I select Complete Installation option.

I am reached up to follow window but few second it get Automatically close :

[image]

Two-Three time I have tried to installation but every time installation get close before coming Oracle product installation list.

I am completely blank, why this ?

Please some body help me for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot the installation based on installation log files which are available in

```
  oracle_inventory\logs\installActionstimestamp.log

  oracle_inventory\logs\oraInstalltimestamp.err

  oracle_inventory\logs\oraInstalltimestamp.out
```

where

The form of timestamp in the file log name  is

```
 yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss[AM|PM] where:

 yyyy is the current year, for example 2003

 mm is the current month number, for example 07 for July

 dd is the current day number, for example 15 for the fifteenth

 hh, mm, and ss are the hour, minute, and second at which the installation started

 [AM/PM] is either AM or PM, depending on when the installation started
```

and

```
the location of the oracle_inventory directory is specified 
during the first installation of an Oracle product on your computer
(for example oracle client or oracle database etc)
```

In My system the location is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\logs
```

Once you get the installation log you can trouble shoot the issue using search engine or post in  oracle forums

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for the above issue.

1. I have uninstalled the oracle 11g database.
2. installed the oracle 10g forms and report.
3. installed the oracle 11g DB.

Now it's working fine.